# Mysql dump restoring

Tags: mysql

I ran into a big trouble. I made mysql dump using version 5.0.77 without setting the compatibility mode (I wasn't aware of this problem). Actual mysql server is version 4.0.18. Today our database crashed. Lots of tables lost. While trying to restore the dump, it's returning error "ERROR 1193 at line 18: Unknown system variable 'character_set_client'". Is there any way we can restore the db?

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: 4.x is end of life?  Planning to upgrade should be in your future.

Answer (score 2):

It may well be worth installing, on another box if required, mysql 5.0.77, restoring, and then re-dumping with the appropriate options.

This isn't an elegant solution, but if you're in "big trouble" and need something that works and fast, this is the first thing that jumped into my mind.

Comment: Didn't worked :( I restored the dump to a mysql server 5.0.77 and took dump from it with --compatible=mysql40. But still mysql dump kept the "character_set_client" info. So unable to restore it. Damn! it's running production server and clients are all over me :(

Comment: @saif Can you run your production off the 5x version of the database?

Comment: On the plus side you know that that particular flag wasn't the issue...

Comment: This just reminded me... I need to go test all my backups.

Answer (score 1):

Hope your dump file isn't too big. **Copy it** and edit it. If it's really large, use `sed` or a script. If it's small enough, vim it.

`sed '/\/*!40101 SET character_set_client'/d < original > copy`

Anywhere you see the string `/*!40101 SET character_set_client` delete that line. The server doesn't understand it anyway and it won't affect your data.

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `locationId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `releaseDate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`releaseDate`,`locationId`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing this from a *copy* of the dump, just in case...

Comment: @BartSilverstrim I'll just go ahead and bold that then :)

Comment: Emphasis for backup and copies as it's an easy thing to overlook when panicking!